# Authentication from session into members folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have set up member folders in c# asp.net webforms before to only allow certain users and to redirect if the user is not authenticated.  I am wondering is this possible / how would I implement the authentication based on weather a Session variable is present(filled with a value) or not authenticate if the Session is null.

I was hoping that something like this would be possible similar to how you can set permissions in we.config for entire folder.

Comment: Have you considered using a custom role provider instead? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74.aspx

Comment: that's just what I thought , I really would like to find a way to verify user with session , if that is possible it would save a lot of work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123143/asp-net-mvc-3-dealing-with-session-variables

Check this out. Its similar to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done with help of standart asp.net features. I will try to advice one possible solution for it. First you need to setup "web form authentication" [ASP.NET Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa291347%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), you should modify your web.config.

```
<system.web>
   <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="Custom" loginUrl="/login.aspx" />       
   </authentication>
</system.web>
```

Then you need to specify members locations in the web.config also [ASP.NET Authorization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/8d82143t.aspx).

```
<location path="folders/memberN">
   <system.web>
      <authorization>
         <allow roles="memberN"/>
         <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
   </system.web>
</location>
```

This will allow all users in group "memberN" to work under "folders/memberN" path.

Next we need to add [membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/1b9hw62f.aspx) and [role providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms164660.aspx) to your web.config. Membership and role providerse configured based on sql server provider.

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="SqlServices" 
             connectionString="Data Source=MySqlServer;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial 
             Catalog=aspnetdb;" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
        <roleManager defaultProvider="SqlProvider" 
          enabled="true"
          cacheRolesInCookie="true"
          cookieName=".ASPROLES"
          cookieTimeout="30"
          cookiePath="/">
          <providers>
            <add
              name="SqlProvider"
              type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"
              connectionStringName="SqlServices" 
              applicationName="SampleApplication" />
          </providers>
        </roleManager>
        <membership 
             defaultProvider="SqlProvider"
             userIsOnlineTimeWindow="20">
             <providers>
                <remove name="AspNetSqlProvider" />
                <add name="SqlProvider"
                    type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
                    connectionStringName="SqlServices"
                    applicationName="/" />
            </providers>
        </membership>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Finnaly we need to create special tabels in the database ([more details](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020203214/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/040506-1.aspx)).

```
%WINDOWS%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regsql.exe -S <server> -E -d <database> -A all
```